# Как добавить таксономию для записи через админку?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал 2 таксономии :

```
function add_new_taxonomies() { 

register_taxonomy('countries',
    array('post'),
    array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        /* true - по типу рубрик, false - по типу меток, 
        по умолчанию - false */
        'labels' => array(
            /* ярлыки, нужные при создании UI, можете
            не писать ничего, тогда будут использованы
            ярлыки по умолчанию */
            'name' => 'Countries',
            'singular_name' => 'Country',
            'search_items' =>  'Search country',
            'popular_items' => 'Popular country',
            'all_items' => 'All countries',
            'parent_item' => null,
            'parent_item_colon' => null,
            'edit_item' => 'Redact country', 
            'update_item' => 'Refrash country',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add new country',
            'new_item_name' => 'New country name',
            'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate countries with commas',
            'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove countries',
            'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from most used',
            'menu_name' => 'Countries'
        ),
        'public' => true, 
        /* каждый может использовать таксономию, либо
        только администраторы, по умолчанию - true */
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        /* добавить на страницу создания меню */
        'show_ui' => true,
        /* добавить интерфейс создания и редактирования */
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        /* нужно ли разрешить облако тегов для этой таксономии */
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        /* callback-функция для обновления счетчика $object_type */
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        /* разрешено ли использование query_var, также можно 
        указать строку, которая будет использоваться в качестве 
        него, по умолчанию - имя таксономии */
        'rewrite' => array(
        /* настройки URL пермалинков */
            'slug' => 'countries', // ярлык
            'hierarchical' => false // разрешить вложенность

        ),
    )
);

register_taxonomy('cities',
    array('post'),
    array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        /* true - по типу рубрик, false - по типу меток, 
        по умолчанию - false */
        'labels' => array(
            /* ярлыки, нужные при создании UI, можете
            не писать ничего, тогда будут использованы
            ярлыки по умолчанию */
            'name' => 'Cities',
            'singular_name' => 'City',
            'search_items' =>  'Search city',
            'popular_items' => 'Popular city',
            'all_items' => 'All cities',
            'parent_item' => null,
            'parent_item_colon' => null,
            'edit_item' => 'Redact city', 
            'update_item' => 'Refrash city',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add new city',
            'new_item_name' => 'New city name',
            'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate cities with commas',
            'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove cities',
            'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from most used',
            'menu_name' => 'Cities'
        ),
        'public' => true, 
        /* каждый может использовать таксономию, либо
        только администраторы, по умолчанию - true */
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        /* добавить на страницу создания меню */
        'show_ui' => true,
        /* добавить интерфейс создания и редактирования */
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        /* нужно ли разрешить облако тегов для этой таксономии */
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        /* callback-функция для обновления счетчика $object_type */
        'query_var' => true,
        'meta_box_cb'  => 'post_categories_meta_box',
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        /* разрешено ли использование query_var, также можно 
        указать строку, которая будет использоваться в качестве 
        него, по умолчанию - имя таксономии */
        'rewrite' => array(
        /* настройки URL пермалинков */
            'slug' => 'cities', // ярлык
            'hierarchical' => false // разрешить вложенность

        ),
    )
);
```

}

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_new_taxonomies', 0 );
```

При создании записи нету никакого UI для выбора таксономии

Comment: Выглядит правильно, куда вы код добавляете? P.S. слаги countries, cities - должны быть в единственном числе: country, city.

Comment: в functions.php
В самом меню таксономии есть, но нету функционала  добавления таксономии для записи

Comment: У поста вверху справа есть язычок "Настройки экрана" там нужно включить ваши таксономии для отображение на посте

Comment: Да, но если я правильно понимаю где то тут http://joxi.ru/bmowdQpI9kxNnm  должна появится такая возможность

Comment: Должны появится там, но их нужно включить вверху страницы, если они выключены